# How to get card brand using Stripe and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

```
    STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams) { (token, error) in
        if error != nil {
            //fail
        } else if let token = token {
            print(token.card?.brand) //Optional(__C.STPCardBrand)
            print(token.card?.brand.hashValue) //Optional(0)
            print(token.card?.brand.rawValue) //Optional(0)
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know why Stripe isn't returning the card brand? I'm using a Stripe test card and the rest of the info is getting returned.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So checking the API documentation I found that `brand` is en enum:

```
var brand: STPCardBrand { get }
```

having these values:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, STPCardBrand) {
    STPCardBrandVisa,
    STPCardBrandAmex,
    STPCardBrandMasterCard,
    STPCardBrandDiscover,
    STPCardBrandJCB,
    STPCardBrandDinersClub,
    STPCardBrandUnknown,
};
```

You could also consider using the static `stringFromBrand` function:

> Returns a string representation for the provided card brand; i.e.
>   [NSString stringFromBrand:STPCardBrandVisa] == @"Visa". Declaration
>
> - (nonnull NSString *)stringFromBrand:(STPCardBrand)brand;
>
> class func string(from brand: STPCardBrand) -> String

Example:

```
print(STPCard.stringFromBrand(from: token.card?.brand))
```

Swift 4:

```
print(STPCard.string(from: token.card!.brand))
```

Comment: Can I get card Brand without generating Token?

Comment: what is mean by token?

Answer (score 2):

@OlegDanu's answer with unwrapping

As he said use `STPCard.stringFromBrand(from: token.card?.brand)` but card? is an Optional of type `STPCard` and I didn't realize that and spent some time trying to unwrap it. Anyway it's best to unwrap it first

```
if let card = token.card { }
```

Here's the code below

```
STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: card, completion: { 
    [weak self] (token, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    guard let token = token else { return }

    // card is an Optional of type STPCard
    if let card = token.card {

       let brand = STPCard.string(from: card.brand)

       print(brand)
    }
})
```

Comment: cardparams mean card cardnumber?

Comment: Where do you see cardparams at?

Comment: card parameter you passed while creating a token?

Comment: @Arigarasuthan yeah it's the card params. I get the card from the **STPPaymentCardTextField** textField. The card entered into the textField is of type **STPPaymentMethodCardParams**. Basically the card number that the user enters into that textField.

Comment: yes it's working thank you.if i want to generate a token publishing key need?